# Где хранить данные о котировках большого количества валют?

Tags: база-данных, хранение-данных, clickhouse

Получаю по средствам API различных бирж данные о курсах валют.Всего получается около 3000 курсов, каждый содержит в себе данные о цене за каждую минуту на протяжении года.Соответственно получается около 1.5 млрд записей.Вопрос, где все это добро хранить?

Answer (score 0):

можно сохранить в  txt на флешку)) Если по делу: 
 Нужно знать как вы собираетесь использовать эти данные, как часто получать результаты. Если это для программы, которая должна по указанной дате и валюте выдать её курс, то встает вопрос: а зачем вы всю эту БД сразу скачиваете? на то и нужно API этих бирж, чтобы выдавать вам именно то, что нужно в данный момент. Хотите всё скачать и больше не обращаться к API? ))   Я делал логику такой: сделал запрос, проверил есть ли в БД результат, если есть показал, если нет делаю запрос к API биржи - получил ответ, показал, сохранил в БД.

Comment: Мне нужно выводить эти курсы в виде графиков на сайте, количество запросов к API ограниченно, по этому мне необходимо сохранять данные и после выводить их уже из БД. И новые данные поступают каждую минуту, соответсвенно их нужно добавлять к остальным.

Comment: А графики требуются именно с поминутным разрешением? Если нет, то можно усреднять данные и таким образом сократить объем в десятки раз.

Comment: Ну все равно не пойму, где вы еще хотите хранить данные, если не в БД ? ведь нужна будет быстрая выборка. Например надо вывести график за  прошлую неделю. Делаете запрос за каждый час в течении недели. Думаю этих точек достаточно чтобы график рисовать. Ну и сохраняете в БД. В БД тоже ведь не сложно их хранить. Название валюты, плюс время уже вместе являются уникальным идентификатором, чтобы делать выборку из БД.

Comment: avp, я думаю объем весь вообще не скачивается , нафига вообще тогда нужно API, да и какое API выдает всю БД сразу ? Вопрос немного некорректно поставлен, инфы мало.

Comment: @Turalllb, конечно база выбирается частями. Раз в час  (или ежедневно) делается выборка по API. Вот раз в день новые данные можно усреднять (скажем, на интервал в 1 час) и в БД хранить для графиков уже их.

Comment: @avp Актуальный данные за сутки мне нужны именно с интервалом в 1 миниту, остальные же возможно и стоит "Постепенно" усреднять, т.е. данные за текущую неделю должны быть с интервалом в 30 минут, за месяц с интервалом в час и тд. Вопрос теперь в другом, какую БД выбрать для этих целей?Сейчас смотрю в сторону Clickhouse от яндекса,что на счет неё?

Comment: вам правильно сказали выше - не надо хранить полную версию, ибо НИКОГДА И НИКТО не использует её даже на 10%!! получили запрос ни инфо - проверили, есть ли уже в вашей БД - если нет, тащите в свою БД - на этом все! Что такое "кол-во запросов к АПИ ограничено" ???!!! детский лепет какой-то... или халява душит?